# Mergesort stack (using only extra stacks, but with as many as needed)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, recursion

I'm reading a problem out of Cracking the Coding Interview, and the author describes the solution to the problem described in the title as follows:

> With the merge sort solution, we would create two extra stacks and divide the stack into two. > parts. we would recursively sort each stack, and then merge them back together in sorted order into the original stack. Note that this requires creation of two additional stack per level of recursion.

I'm trying to understand the time complexity. I'm assuming (though could be totally wrong) that the two extra stacks are needed because when merging two stacks in ascending order bottom-up, we have to repeatedly pop smallest elements from both stacks into stack 2, then pop all of stack 2 into stack 1 to get ascending order of all the elements. This process is O(N) for every level of recursion, and since we're recursively operating on halves it would be O(logN) levels..correct? So is this an O(NlogN) time algorithm? And O(N) space complexity?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, note that each of the created stacks is *half* the size of the parent stack.  The sum of stack sizes at each level of recursion is N.  This much gives you space complexity of O(N log N).

However, you can do better.  If you reclaim each stack once you've split it in two (on the way down) and reclaim the sub-stacks as you merge them (on the way up), you can, indeed, hold your space to O(N).

Answer (score 0):

Using 4 stacks and bottom up merge sort would be faster. Call the stacks A, B, C, and D, with the data initially on stack A (B, C, D empty). Split the elements (pop / push) from A alternating into C and D (1 element to C, 1 element to D, ...). Then merge runs from C and D alternating the merged run output between A and B (on the first pass 2 elements to A, 2 elements to B, ...) . Then merge runs from A and B, alternating output to C and D (on the second pass, 4 elements to C, 4 elements to D, ...) . Repeat the process until there is just one sorted run. The sense of the compare is reversed on each "pass" (reversed for C,D -> A,B, not reversed for A,B -> C,D). The size of B, C, D would need to be the same as A, unless stacks are implemented using single linked lists. The same logic could be used with 4 FIFO queues, except the sense of compare would never need to be reversed.

---

For a 3 stack bottom up merge sort, call the stacks A, B, C, with the data initially on A, (B, C empty). Split the elements (pop / push) from A alternating into B and C. Then merge an element from B with an element from C, and push the result in A, resulting in sorted runs of size 2 in A. Then A is split again, only this time alternating between moving two elements from A to B and moving two elements from A to C. Then "runs" of size 2 are merged from B and C back into A, creating runs of size 4. Since the element are pushed in reverse order when moving from A to B or C, the sense of the compare needs to be reversed, for example use > to replace <= for an ascending (or original order if equal) sort. The size of B, C would need to be the same as A, unless stacks are implemented using single linked lists. This is about twice as slow as the 4 stack version, since after each merge pass, the data has to be redistributed from A to B and C.

---

For a 3 stack sort, a variation of bottom up merge sort called polyphase merge sort is the fastest method, since it only needs a one time distribution, but polyphase 3 stack sort is complicated. A 3 stack polyphase merge sort is almost as fast as a 4 stack regular bottom up merge sort. Which is faster depends if number of elements is merge friendly (power of 2) or polyphase friendly (a Fibonacci number).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyphase_merge_sort